# pandas get a value out of text using regex

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, regex-lookarounds

i have a text like this:

```
text = 'Ronald Mayr: A\nBell Kassulke: B\nJacqueline Rupp: A \nAlexander Zeller: C\nValentina Denk: C \nSimon Loidl: A \nElias Jovanovic: B \nStefanie Weninger: B \nFabian Peer: C \nHakim Botros: B\nEmilie Lorentsen: B\n'
```

I need to get all the names that have ":B" value.. for example Bell Kassulke, Elias Jovanovic

I'm trying something like this

```
stu = re.findall('\w+.*.: B',text)
```

but this one gives me list like this:

```
['Bell Kassulke: B',
 'Simon Loidl: B',
 'Elias Jovanovic: B']
```

While I only need the names not this whole list. What exactly can I do?

Comment: to eliminate ": B " from the result :  stu = str(stu).replace(': B','')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^(.*?):\s*B\s*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mYFWeY/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1 (the actual value of `.findall`): any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*B\s*` - a `B` enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
- `$` - end of string/

In Pandas, you may use

```
df['Col name here'].str.findall(r'^(.*?):\s*B\s*$').str.join(',')
```

Or, if you need a single match per value:

```
df['Results'] = df['Col name here'].str.extract(r'^(.*?):\s*B\s*$', expand=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

'('  starts capturing

> \w+

matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])

> - 

Quantifier — Matches between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

> .*

matches any character (except for line terminators)

> - 

Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)

')'  end of capturing

> : B

matches the characters : B literally (case sensitive)

```
pattern='(\w+.*.): B'
re.findall(pattern,grades)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this line of code after your regex:

```
stu = [s.replace(': B', '') for s in stu]
```